# Stopping :PluginInstall safely

Tags: plugin-vundle

Is there a way to stop PluginInstall while it's running.

The typical scenario in which I need this is when installing a new plugin (basically one line added to the `.vimrc`), and once PluginInstall passes that line in the list of plugins, it's not going to be doing anything useful any more. I'd rather stop it manually than wait 10-20 more seconds for it to finish going over the list.

Answer (score 2):

Vundle calls `system()` to run `git`.

> ```
>   The command will be executed in "cooked" mode, so that a
>   CTRL-C will interrupt the command (on Unix at least).
> ```

If you cancel Vundle, Vim will interrupt git. So the question is are you able to stop git safely? Since you can find posts about broken git repos the answer is probably no.

A better alternative might be [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) which is very quick on `:PlugInstall`.

Comment: What does "cooked" mode mean?

Comment: @AssafLavie that's a tty mode, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooked_mode